# Java turn String from Database into Class Object

Tags: java, sql, oracle, class, casting

I'm trying to cast a String into an Class object. I have bookings which also consist of an object from the Class Room. I save my Bookings in an oracle database but I only save the Roomnumer as a String since you cant save Rooms in oracle. If I load my Bookings from my database I need to convert the roomnumber back into a Room object. I don't know if what I tried to do is the right way, it works but maybe someone knows an easier way to do this since I'm still a beginner.

Here is what I have so far: 
I load my bookings from my database and while setting my variables I use the setRoom method to change the String roomNumber into a room by going through all my Rooms and checking wether there is a room with the same number

```
public void setRoom(String roomNr) {

        Collection<Room> roomList = new ArrayList<Room>();
        roomList = rManager.loadAllRooms();

        for (Room r : roomList) {
            if (r.getRoomNr().equals(roomNr)) {
                this.room = r;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to create a new `Room` object with the data from the database. *"I save my Bookings in an oracle database but I only save the Roomnumer as a String since you cant save Rooms in oracle"* - Well, technically, you'd have a table called `Room` which held all the properties of the "room", you'd define a primary key for the "room" which would then create a foreign key constraint into other tables, which can be used to get the room information through reverse lookups

Comment: Your question is not related to casting I'd think. But what's the question or problem you have? Otherwise it's probably more a candidate for a code review.

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes I have a Table for my Rooms and it's primary key is saved in my Booking table as a foreign key. How would I be able to get this information in java to set my Room? Sorry if this is a stupid question but like I said I'm still new to this.

Comment: @DennisHunziker it's not really a "Problem", I just thought that there might be a better way to handle this and I wasn't sure if this is a proper way to handle this problem.

Comment: @Hola You pull the data from the database, you use the classes constructor and/or settings to apply the data to the object

Comment: Check out the rManager, but instead of loading all rooms you'll be much better off loading a single room for a particular room number. Unless of course all the rooms in the rManager are loaded and then cached at once but it's impossible for us to see that.